# File Access Temporary Exceptions com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write is this specific to OS X or iOS also

Tags: ios, ipad

Trying to see if we can have "File Access Temporary Exceptions" added to my iOS apps entitlement.plist

i am reading something here
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html

Is this something apple need to allow in provisioning profile ?

Answer (score -1):

According to this document, it's only available in OS X

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH5-SW1